# Symfony2 dev environment not clearing cache automatically

Tags: caching, symfony

I'm working on a new Symfony2 project, and I'm using the app_dev frontcontroller to view the default AcmeDemoBundle's pages.

When I make changes to the controllers, I get an exception (`NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /demo/hello/World"`). If I clear the cache using `php app/console cache:clear`, things work great again. However, it is my understanding that by using the app_dev front controller, I shouldn't be required to do this. Am I doing something wrong?

Soms system specs:
OSX Lion using MAMP
PHP 5.3.6
Symfony 2.0.1

Comment: Great question. I find the caching behavior in dev surprising. `web/app_dev.php` doesn't contain the cache-creating statements that `web/app.php` does.

Comment: I have a problem with cache except for me it's when making changes to my sass files. I've checked the file permissions. Does anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using different users for webserver and command line user? Maybe you should check for permissions in the [Setting up Permissions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html) paragraph.